# How to access information defined in maven’s pom.xml through SonarQube’s Web API?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, pom.xml

SonarQube provides an REST API to access metrics and other information. https://sonarqube.com/web_api/

How can information provided in maven’s pom.xml (e.g. version, artifactId, groupId, custom properties) be queried via SonarQube’s Web API?

Thanks in advance for any hints in the right direction.

Comment: You should clarify why you want to go through SonarQube (code quality tool) to read `pom.xml` attributes (unrelated to code quality), rather then just checking-out the file and reading it.

Comment: I’m trying to collect and analyse statistics and provide them to another service. I obviously can get all the metrics from SonarQube’s WebAPI, but so far not the other values. So I’m wondering whether this information can also be accessed though the same API as well, as the values(e.g. maven-version of the build used in SonarQube) seem to be known to SonarQube.